Decryption DES in angular
I have this function in the company server to decrypt strings written in C#:
public static string Decrypt(string text)
{
   SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = DES.Create();
   ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
   byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
   byte[] bytes = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(array, 0, array.Length);
   return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
}

this is my angular function (the current one, i have tried several times with no success):
decryptDES(text: string): string {
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(text, this.key, {
      iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(this.iv),
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    });

    return CryptoJS.enc.Utf16.stringify(decrypted);
  }

example key and iv from c#:
private static byte[] key = new byte[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
private static byte[] iv = new byte[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

encrypted string - "hMm+7trOFhZNrLBiWsrfzYT2x8oqeIx3"
the result after decryption needs to be "only_once"
I need to write the same function in my angular app.

Encoding.Unicode.GetString is already concerning. You definitely shouldn't be using this to get a human-readable form of your encrypted data. You should be using something like Convert.ToBase64String or Convert.ToHexString (or BitConverter.ToString if your version of .NET doesn't have ToHexString).  Basically, not every byte combination can be converted to a string, so converting bytes->Unicode->bytes will give you a different set of bytes to the input. Before you even write an Angular equivalent, you have to fix this mess.

I cant change this function, this is on the company server and already used in some other places.

@ProgrammingLlama - That's true for encryption. But the question is about decryption. Decoding the decrypted plaintext with Encoding.Unicode (more precisely with UTF16-LE) is unproblematic (as long as the original plaintext was encoded with UTF-16LE). By the way, the ciphertext is Base64 encoded (as can be seen in the code snippet).

Post your most recent Angular code along with non-productive test data (key, IV, ciphertext, expected plaintext) and describe the problem. Note that DES has been retired 20 years ago and is insecure.

HTTPS already provides far stronger encryption that the DES algorithm that was completely broken over 20 years ago - as in broken using brute force in seconds

Why are you doing this at all? I can't stress enough how broken this is. Essentially, you're using cleartext. The compiler already generates Obsoletion warnings that you chose to ignore. Blazor won't even allow this call and throw an UnsupportedOSPlatform exception. .NET itself has far better encryption mechanisms and HTTPS/TLS1.2 is far more secure than DES ever was.

You must convert the key and IV into a WordArray in the CryptoJS code. How this is done in detail depends on the encoding of the values. What exactly do this.iv and this.key look like? Please complete the CryptoJS code to an executable code so that the import can be checked! Also, you are using the wrong encoder when decoding the decrypted plaintext. MS refers to UTF-16LE as Unicode, which means you must apply CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.

this is the key and iv - key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('12345678');
iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('12345678');

This is wrong. The hex encoding of the posted C# key is 0x0102030405060708, so the right WordArray conversion is: var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0102030405060708') (for the IV it is analogous).

@Topaco Oh, I'm a fool. I got it into my head, somehow, that it was an encryption method. Thank you for pointing that out.
